# Determine model parameters without model.parameters()

Tags: python, parameters, pytorch, model

I would like to determine the model parameters for my pytorch models.
Unfortunately, I can't use the `model.parameters()` method because not every model uses `torch.nn`.

Can I calculate the model parameters from the dictionary I get from `torch.load(model_path)`?
I would have added the lengths of the lists for this and for matrices, added the dimensions together.

```
model_parameter += len(list) # add 5 if list is 5 long
model_parameter += x.shape[0] * x.shape[1] # x is matrix with dimension 3x4, then model_parameter gets 12 added to it
```

I don't need the exact number of model parameters. I need these numbers to roughly compare the models. (Is model A twice as big as model B etc.).

Or do you know better ways how I can calculate this without using `model.load_state_dict()` and `model.parameters()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you can't use the `model.parameters()` but if you do not care about trainable/non-trainable parameters you can try to use `torch.save` to get the model size:

```
import io
import torch
from torchvision.models import resnet18
model = resnet18()
buffer = io.BytesIO()
torch.save(model, buffer)
print(f"Size of the model: {buffer.tell()} bytes")
```